# What does it mean to "top deck"?

Tags: terminology, hearthstone

I see this term getting thrown around a lot in the Hearthstone community and not a lot of context is there to fully understand its' meaning.

What does it mean if someone is "topdecking"?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Top decking can be one of two things.

1. Your hand is empty and your hand each turns consists of the card from the top of your deck.

   ex. "His hand is toast, he'll be top-decking for the rest of the game."
2. On your beginning-of-turn draw, you've drawn exactly the card you need in that particular situation in order to save yourself. (e.g. Flamestrike vs a hunter with a full board)

   ex. "I can't believe he top-decked a Flamestrike! I had him next turn!"

[As gatherer818 mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246958/what-does-it-mean-to-top-deck#comment341063_246959), this is a very old term originating in tabletop collectible card games. [Here is a discussion thread on the Hearthstone forums about it](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/11422462743).

Comment: It might be worth noting this is general card game lingo;  I first heard it around fifteen years ago when playing against someone with a much more powerful deck than me in Magic the Gathering.  He searched my hand one turn to make sure I didn't have any counters I could afford, then next turn dumped an instant-win combo on me - and I redirected it back on him and won instantly.  "I cannot.  Believe.  You top-decked a friggin' Misdirection.  Good game."  (He won games 2 and 3, unsurprisingly, but several people were impressed by the one win anyway.)

Comment: The saying is "it's not over until it's over."

Comment: @gatherer818 Very true. That's actually when I first heard the term as well.

Comment: Where you with him when his story happened or how could that be the event where you heared it first too? xD

Comment: @Zaibis `I first heard it around fifteen years ago when playing ... Magic the Gathering` << that's when I first heard it too. :)